# Recreating natural link click event after preventing default

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

```
$(document).on('click','a',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    sendAnalytics("clicked a link",function(){
        // on success callback, continue with link's redirect
        window.location = href;
        //   or location.assign(href);
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location = href;
    },5e3); // just incase callback never fires
});
```

How can I simulate the default link clicking behavior in this example? I notice that if I open in a new tab (<kbd>control+click</kbd>, or <kbd>middle-click</kbd>), it still redirects the current tab.

I know I can catch each click and detect if it is middle vs. left mouse, but is there an easier way to accomplish this, including things like <kbd>control+click</kbd> ?

---

So far the only alternative I see is to store the values in a cookie, then on each pageload read cookies, send analytics, and delete cookies.

Comment: Why wait for a callback function if you're going to redirect them either way?

Comment: @php_nub_qq its a common practice to ensure the request is received by the analytics platform before redirecting. otherwise, you may redirect before the request is sent or recorded.

Comment: but what difference does it make if you're going to redirect them in both cases? You're going to have a really hard time "recreating natural link click"

Comment: It's impossible, just use server side redirection like everyone else, including Google.

Comment: Does removing `e.preventDefault()` and your `window.location` redirect work?

Comment: @php_nub_qq the same reason why Google Analytics has https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en, and why mixpanel has http://blog.mixpanel.com/2012/10/08/link-tracking-in-mixpanel/, etc....

Comment: Best way I can think of is to set `async` to `false` in the `$.ajax` options, although this will make the browser freeze until the the request is complete.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it. But when your user middle- or ctrl-clicks, the target page will open in a new tab, so the current page shouldn't be redirecting anywhere and stay as is. IMHO that's the point of opening links in new tabs or windows.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you're trying to intercept the link click event, send some analytics data, then recreate the click to continue with navigation. So, to do that:

```
function NewTab(url) {
    var newTab = window.open(url,"_blank");
    newTab.focus();
}

$("a").on("click", function(e) {    // more efficient

    var href = $(this).attr("href");

    if(e.ctrlKey) {   // ctrl to open in a new tab

        sendAnalytics("clicked a link", function() {
            NewTab(href);
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            location.href = href;
        }, 5e3);
    }

    else {
        sendAnalytcis("clicked a link", function() {
            location.href = href;
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            location.href = href;
        }
    }
});
```

First I create a new tab function that I can use if the user has control-clicked the link. Then I intercept the click, and if the Control key was pressed, I send analytics then open the link in a new tab. Otherwise, I send the analytics then redirect the current tab. The backups are still there in case the callback doesn't fire.

As a footnote, the simplest way to recreate a 'natural link click' is `$(this).click();`

Hope this helps!
-CE